# Faster way to Select before and after of selected row

Tags: mysql, performance

I'm currently using this way for selecting before and after of selected row:

```
SELECT rank, id FROM (
  SELECT
    id,
    @i:=@i + 1 rank,
    @match:=IF(table.id = 50, @i, @match)
  FROM
    table t,(SELECT @i:=0, @match:=0) vars
  ORDER BY t.t_date DESC
) t2
WHERE
@match>=rank-1 AND @match<=rank+1;
```

As you can see I selected equal, before and after rows id=50.

**Question: I'm creating match row with IF condition and place it inside var. Is it this way memory and performance efficient?**

Comment: Do you need the rank in the result? Or do you just want to know the ids of the row before and after your id? You didn't specify an order - is it ordered by id or do you want it to be ordered by a non-indexes column? (E.g: do you want to get `48, 50, 51` if `49` doesn't exist?)

Comment: @Solarflare No I don't need rank in the result. It's just sample for showing how I fetch before and after row and Yes I want to know ID at last. My original sub query is different from this. In the sample I just want to show the way I fetching after and before row. I want to know is there any other syntax with better performance or Is my way for fetching after and before memory and performance efficient? and for Your last question. My Real Sub query is ordering by date and the main thing for finding the row is id just like I showed in the sample.

Answer (score 0):

MariaDB 10.2 implements a lot of Window Functions, and does it efficiently.

[*Reference*](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/window-functions/)